# SQL::Abstract insert row using MySQL value of now()

Tags: mysql, perl

How can I construct an SQL::Abstract call to create a row such that the column 'date' is populated with the value of the MySQL function now() ?

This is as far as I have got with the SQL::Abstract. I do realise this will tie me to databases that understand the now() function, but that is okay.

```
$result = $schema->resultset('Batch')->create(
        {   date => 'now()',    # <- Please help. Here?
        }
    );
```

This would be the corresponding raw SQL:

```
insert into batch (date) values (now());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is how you do it:

```
$result = $schema->resultset('Batch')->create( {
    'date' => \'now()',
} );
```

Comment: Note: if you want to use the date property, you need to refetch result object.